# Filtering stored procedure records by nested select case statement

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, case-statement

I need to further refine my stored proc resultset from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25767993/3929962), I need to filter my resultset to display only records where emailaddr is NULL (meaning display only records that have `Invoice_DeliveryType` value of 'N' ).

Among numerous queries, I have tried:

```
select 
    Invoice_ID, 'Unknown' as Invoice_Status, 
    case when Invoice_Printed is null then '' else 'Y' end as Invoice_Printed, 
    case when Invoice_DeliveryDate is null then '' else 'Y' end as Invoice_Delivered, 
    (case when Invoice_DeliveryType <> 'USPS' then ''
          when exists (Select 1
                   from dbo.Client c
                   Where c.Client_ID = SUBSTRING(i.Invoice_ID, 1, 6) and
                         c.emailaddr is not null
                  )
          then 'Y'
          else 'N'
     end)
    Invoice_ContactLName + ', ' + Invoice_ContactFName as ContactName, 
from 
    dbo.Invoice
left outer join 
    dbo.fnInvoiceCurrentStatus() on Invoice_ID = CUST_InvoiceID 
where 
    CUST_StatusID = 7 
    AND Invoice_ID = dbo.Client.Client_ID
    AND dbo.client.emailaddr is NULL
order by 
    Inv_Created
```

but I get an error

> The conversion of the nvarchar value '20111028995999' overflowed an int column

How can I get the stored procedure to only return records with `DeliveryType = 'N'` ?

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://sqlcuriosities.weebly.com/1/post/2011/11/sql-server-error-conversion-of-nvarchar-value-overflowed-an-int-column.html

Comment: The `Invoice_ID = dbo.Client.Client_ID` and `dbo.client.emailaddr is NULL` predicates don't make any sense: there's no `dbo.Client` in your query at that level.

Comment: Also, it doesn't really help to understand the problem better that some columns in your query aren't qualified with table references.

Answer (score 1):

Trying selecting the stored proc results into a temp table, then select
* from #TempTable

Comment: I tried using a temptable (http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC) but I get an error "An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested."

Answer (score 0):

We could really do with a schema definition to get this problem resolved.

It appears that there is an implicit conversion occurring within one of your case statements, but without the schema def's it's difficult to track down which one.

You can't safely mix datatypes in CASE expressions, unless you are absolutely sure that any implicit conversions will work out OK you should make the conversions explicit.

Judging by the error message seeming to include something that could be a date represented as a string(`20111028`) plus some kind of other data ?time?(`995999`) it may be something to do with `Invoice_DeliveryDate`, but this is a shot in the dark without more details.

Comment: that error was also occurring in the previous post, but in that situation, when I added "c.emailaddr is not null", the query worked perfectly.